# Randomly select vertices to be beacons

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, jgrapht

In our programming assignment, we are tasked with shortest path routing with randomized beacons. Given a graph with *n* vertices and *p* beacons that are to be randomly chosen from the vertex set, we are to find the shortest path between two vertices *s* and *t* by pre-computing the all-pair shortest paths between any pair of beacons. In other words, we are to compute the shortest path between *s* and its nearest beacon *b1*, *t* and its nearest beacon *b2*, and the shortest path between *b1* and *b2*. We are using the JGraphT component of Java, so both vertices and beacons are the same type of object *V*. My question is, how do I randomly select beacons from the set of vertices, and how do I store the all-pair shortest paths after pre-computing them?

Comment: i have mistake in wrong question.

Comment: The usual way to store one scalar per unique pair is in a 2d matrix.  If the order within the pairs doesn't matter (that is, s[i,j] == s[j,i]), i.e. if your graph is undirected, then you need only a triangular array.  The square one would be symmetric.

Pick vertices exactly the same way you would select integers from a hat. The hat is a list of integers x from 0 to n-1.  Generate a random integer with r =  Random.nextInt(n). This gives you the index of the first choice.  A handy thing to do is swap x[r] and x[n-1].  Now the list from 0 to n-2 is the hat. Select and swap this way p times.

Comment: @Gene thank you, that makes sense! Could you possibly provide a small example of this in Java code?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Since it's your programming assignment, can you show what you've done already and show us where you got stuck? Make sure to include an [example].

Comment: No. I'm with @JorisKinable. You'll never learn the art of writing code for an algorithm if you never do it.  This is a CS1 or 2 level problem, so I assume you aspire to be a computer scientist at some level. This is where you start!  Have fun! The thrill when you figure it out is worth the struggle.

Comment: Ok, let me know if I'm on the right track here: `List<V> beacons = new ArrayList<>(p * p);
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {int r = rng.nextInt(n * n);
            beacons.add(nodes.remove(r));`